# More than 1 Dropdown lists HTML/PHP-Mysql

Tags: php, html, drop-down-menu, html-select

How can i populate a mysql database with more than 1 dropdown lists ?

My code in html page is:

```
<form method="post" action="submit.php">

Number:  <select name="number">
  <option value="535">535</option>
  <option value="338">228</option></select>
<br>

Name: <select name="name">
<option value="John">John</option>
<option value="Dave">Dave</option></select>
<br>

<input type="submit" value="Add" />
</form>
```

My code in php is:

```
$Number = $_POST['number'] ;
$Name = $_POST['name'] ;

$query = "INSERT INTO submit (Number,Name) VALUES ('number','name')";

mysql_query($query) or die('Error Updating Database');
echo "Added";
```

Comment: Aren't you already two dropdown lists? And mind that a malicious user can just inject SQL into your database if that is your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes**, you can store the values from two different select lists in a MySQL query, but you need to actually insert the values that come back in `$Number` and `$Name` like so:

```
$Number = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['number']);
$Name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);

$query = "INSERT INTO submit (Number,Name) VALUES ('$Number','$Name')";

mysql_query($query) or die('Error Updating Database');
echo "Added";
```

I have also added [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) to help sanitise the user input before blindly inserting it into a database. This is a basic anti-[SQL Injection](http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/sql-injection.html) measure.

Of course you also need to already be [connected to the MySQL server](http://php.net/mysql_connect) and have [selected a database](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-select-db.php).

Comment: the thing is that i have done it like i said BUT when i press the Add button on my html it justs prompts me to the submit.php page on browser(opens it and it shows me the php code) and it does nothing else

Comment: Sounds like you are not on a PHP enabled host. Are you sure there is PHP on the server? All my comments in my answer above still stand though.

Comment: yup it is enabled.The page worked like charm when i had 1 dropdown list.Then i added the rest drop down lists (4-5) and it stopped working.

Comment: If you are seeing PHP code in the web page then something is wrong with the setup or perhaps the opening `<?php` and/or closing `?>` tags around your PHP code were deleted or edited incorrectly.

Comment: Omg u were right i didnt notice that i had ('number','name') in the query instead of ('$Number','$Name') :)

Comment: Glad I could help. Please mark this question as the answer and up vote it. Thank you.